# Unity3D - How to make a texture changing mute button/toggle?

Tags: audio, menu, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to make a mute button for in my android game menu, so when I press the button, the texture changes from a playing speaker symbol to a muted speaker symbol (which I've already made in Photoshop).

So when the audio is playing it will have a 'speaker' symbol, but when I press it, it will change to a 'muted speaker' symbol (a speaker with a cross).

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first we make a maintexture as the texture that is always used and on awake we put our texture1(speaker) assign to it and if button is pressed we change it to texture2(mute)

```
    public Texture2D Texture1;
    public Texutre2D Texture2;
    public bool textureBool;

    void Awake() {
      textureBool=true;

    void OnGUI(){

    if( GUI.Button( rect , textureBool ? texture1:texture2 ) )
        {
           textureBool = !textureBool;
        }

      }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! But how can I switch it back to texture1(speaker), when I press it again? So it acts like an on/off switch for sound/nosound. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use UI button in this way:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class ChangeSprite : MonoBehaviour {

    public Image image;
    public bool isPress = false;
    public Button button;
    public Sprite Fsprite;
    public Sprite Ssprite;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
         image = button.GetComponent <Image>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame



    public void ChangeSprites () {
        isPress = !isPress;
        if ( isPress == true ) 
        {
            image.sprite = Ssprite;

        }
        else 
        {
            image.sprite = Fsprite;

        }
    }
}
```