# How to save a setting in the menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made a mute button script (for in my menu/pause screen) which has a problem. The mute/unmute part works as I want it to, however whenever I die, and change scenes from 'game' to 'menu', the mute button resets itself to what I've said in the awake function(obviously). But how can I 'save' the mute button state, so when I die it stays to what I've set it to before dying.

Like this: Play the game (unmuted, so **with** sound) -> press pause/die to get to the menu screen -> change button(toggle) to 'mute' (so sound is **off**) -> continue playing/play again -> press pause/die again -> button is still set to 'mute'.

This is my script (sorry it's a bit messy, I'm new to C#):

```
public class MuteButton : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Texture2D Texture1;
    public Texture2D Texture2;
    public Texture2D mainTexture;
    public bool textureBool;

    public int xAs = 290;
    public int yAs = 635;
    public int xSize = 130;
    public int ySize = 130;

    public float native_width = 1080;
    public float native_height = 1920;

    public GUIStyle style = null;

    void Awake() 
    {
        mainTexture = Texture1;
        textureBool = true;
        AudioListener.pause = false;
    }

    void OnGUI() 
    {
        float rx = Screen.width / native_width;
        float ry = Screen.height / native_height;

        GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS (new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, new Vector3(rx, ry, 1)); 

        //if (GUI.Button (new Rect (50,500,50,50),  mainTexture)) 
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (xAs, yAs, xSize, ySize), mainTexture, style))
        {

            if (textureBool)
            {
                mainTexture = Texture2;   //Swap to Texture2
                textureBool = false;
                AudioListener.pause = true;
            }
            else
            {
                mainTexture = Texture1;
                textureBool = true;
                AudioListener.pause = false;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a gameObject to be  persistent you can use

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
```

and to not have two clones of the same game object you should do like this

```
public static exist=false;

Void Awake() {
if (!exist) {
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    exist = true;}
 else {
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

}

one way is to put all your options in class and have sound as a class variable and put in a way that it doesn't destroys

```
public Options option;

      void Start()    
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(option);
        option=option.GetComponent<Options>();
        textureBool=option.sound;  
    }

void died()    
    {
         option.sound=textureBool;
    }
```

a slower but simpler way is pleyerPrefs that is used like this

```
 void Start()    
    {
        textureBool=Convert.ToBoolean(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("sound")) ;
    }


void died()    
    {
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("sound",Convert.ToInt32(textureBool));
         PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll take a look tomorrow, and let you know if it works!

Comment: I´ve taken a look at the code, but because (like I said) I've just started working with C# what you just said is like Chinese to me :p, it's just too much at the same time. That's why I'll ask you, if you have any spare time, could you try to implement your code, into mine? If not, no problem, I understand, but if you do, it's very much appreciated! :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the mean time, I'll try to figure it out by myself :)

Comment: By the way, my menu/dead screen isn't a pop-up, but a separate scene.

Comment: did you used the edited version of the toggle if not use it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998911/unity3d-how-to-make-a-texture-changing-mute-button-toggle)

Comment: if you are developing for windows and want the simple way use `PLayerPrefs`

Comment: Not yet, like I've set it up now, it will change the GUI.Button's position/size for different resolutions. In the edited version I couldn't find out how to do the same. Also, as you can see, I've added a way to turn on/off sound (AudioListener.pause = true/false), I don't know how to add that to the edited script. Maybe it's very easy to do, but I can't see how.

Comment: I am developing for android.

Comment: use whatever you are happy with,and so i add a .save if you want it for android,and if you dont know prefs read [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

Comment: I'll try to figure out what will work for me. Thank you very much for all the information! - Bart