# How to reference a texture with a string?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, texture2d

I've set texture2 to be the new "texture" in the PlayerPrefs like this:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("texture","texture2")
```

But how can I turn the following script's string:

```
PlayerPrefs.GetString("texture")
```

into:

```
mainTexture = PlayerPrefs.GetString("texture")
```

So it will change "texture2" into texture:

```
mainTexture = texture2
```

I'm not using variables because I want the chosen texture to be saved(and loaded). Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out:

I changed PlayerPrefs to:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("tex","texture2")
```

And made one more for texture1.

Then, I made a function called MuteCheck, and this is what I put inside:

```
public void MuteCheck()
{
    texture = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("tex");

    if (texture == "texture2") 
    {
        textureBool = false;
    }
    else if (texture == "texture1")
    {
        textureBool = true;
    }
}
```

After that I mad a Update function like this:

```
 void Update()
{
    if(textureBool == false)
    {
        AudioListener.pause = true;
        mainTexture = Texture2;
    }
    else if(textureBool == true)
    {
        AudioListener.pause = false;
        mainTexture = Texture1;
    }
}
```

And now it works perfectly! :)

Comment: use PlayerPrefs.Save() if you are making for android to be sure data saves if it was pc there was no need

Comment: So in stead of PlayerPrefs.SetString, I should do PlayerPrefs.Save? Or just leave the string and add 'PlayerPrefs.Save' below it?

Comment: no , before changing the scene use PlayerPrefs.Save() dont change anything

Comment: so ,you tested this ,there was no problem

Comment: You mean where I say 'Application.Loadlevel(scene1);' aI also have to write 'PlayerPrefs.Save();? I havent tested it yet, I got tot go now, in a couplet of hours I'll test it. And btw, yesterday I tried it without .Save, and the data just saved as it should do.

Comment: yes before leaving this secne add the save `PlayerPrefs.Save(); Application.Loadlevel(scene1);`

Answer (score 0):

loading a texture by knowing its path is like this

```
string texture = "Assets/Resources/abc.png";
Texture2D inputTexture = (Texture2D)Resources.LoadAssetAtPath(texture, typeof(Texture2D));
```

but that is not what you are looking for
the answer is according to these questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998911/unity3d-how-to-make-a-texture-changing-mute-button-toggle) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023862/how-to-save-a-setting-in-the-menu)
don't convert string to texture make a bool and if it is true so set your texture to tex1 if it is false set it to  tex2

```
 textureBool=Convert.ToBoolean(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("sound")) ;
 if(textureBool)                      //when it is true it means it is mute
     mainTexture=texture2;
  else                                 //when it is false it means the speaker is on
    mainTexture=texture2;
```

Comment: Hello! Ok, You've seen my script, but where exactly do I add your script? Sorry, I'm confused. Btw, thanks for replying to all my questions and helping me out man! :)